Anonymous stack trace for function expressions in safari browser
I am trying to get stack trace of a error which is thrown inside a function expression using console.trace. Int Safari stacktrace does not have function names and instead just gives anonymous functions whereas in mozilla and chrome it gives the function names in the stack trace. Is there anything that I am missing here which can fix this ?
This is the function which should be present in the stacktrace it's there in chrome's stacktrace but not in safari's stacktrace
Safari's Stacktrace 
Chrome's Stacktrace
I added the source map in the main js file but that didn't helped.
Source Map Settings ins Safari 
Source Map Added in the main js file
